# Eagle keyboard shortcuts getting deleted

Tags: eaglecad

Every time I open Eagle, all of the keyboard shortcuts that I had previously assigned are lost.

A web search on how to fix this, or other people reporting this problem has turned up null.

Anyone have this problem too?  If so, anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: You should probably try to find the file where they are saved and monitor it; I know I've backed them up before but don't recall where they were.

Comment: Which eagle version? Which OS?

Comment: @Tom Carpenter I am using Eagle 7.4 on windows 10

Comment: @macdonaldtomw I have this issue to this day and it is driving me crazy

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to import previous saved files, then you should save your file (with the short cuts) prior to exiting Eagle.  When you open Eagle again, import the saved file and continue (your shortcuts should be there).

Answer (score 0):

Eagle stores a lot of settings in the ".efp" file. This is the "project" file.
When you doubleclick a schematic of board file, eagle opens this in the last active project.

It is recommended to open projects via de Control Panel.

For the shortcuts going missing I can provide the advice to create an .SCR file that re-assigns your preferences.

[Example from Sparkfun github](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_Eagle_Settings/blob/master/scr/eagle.scr):

```
# Configuration Script
#
# This file can be used to configure the editor windows.

Assign F3 'Delete';
Assign AF3 'Grid inch 0.001 on; Grid alt inch 0.01;';
Assign F4 'Name';
Assign F5 'Value';
Assign AF5 'Change Text';
Assign F6 'Smash';
Assign F7 'Move';
Assign AF7 'Group';
Assign F8 'Copy';
Assign F10 'Grid inch 0.05 on; Grid alt inch 0.005;';
Assign AF10 'Grid mm 1 on; Grid alt mm 0.1;';
Assign CS+A 'run SparkFun-AutoChecklist.ulp;';
Assign CS+S 'run SparkFun-AutoChecklist-Schematic.ulp;';

Grid inch 0.05 on;
Grid alt inch 0.005;

BRD:
#Menu Add Change Copy Delete Display Grid Group Move Name Quit Rect \
#     Route Script Show Signal Split Text Value Via Window ';'  Wire Write Edit;

#Get rid of the extra internal layers
Set Used_Layers 1 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 91 92 93 94 95 96; 

#Setup SparkFun Defaults
Grid inch 0.05 on;
Grid alt inch 0.005;
Set WIRE_BEND 1; #Route with 45 degree angles
Set Drill 0.015; #Make vias 0.02"
Change Shape Round; #Make vias round
Change Width 0.01; #Routing width default to 10mil
Change Isolate 0.012; #BHW Change polygon isolate to 12mil

Change Font Vector; #Make text on board in vector font
Change Ratio 15;

CHANGE DUNIT INCH OFF #BHW Change default units to inches [ON | OFF] [precision]

#changes background color of board to black
SET PALETTE BLACK;

#Layer colors
Set palette 16 0xFFFFFFFF; #Super white
Set palette 24 0xFFC0C0C0; #Grey - color used when text is selected (anti palette location 16)
Set color_layer 1 4;   #Set top layer to dark red
Set color_layer 16 1;  #Set bottom layer to dark blue
Set color_layer 17 2;  #Set pads to green
Set color_layer 18 2;  #Set vias to green
Set color_layer 19 6;  #Set unrouted to dark yellow
Set color_layer 20 15; #Set dimension to light gray
Set color_layer 21 16; #Set tPlace to white
Set color_layer 22 14; #Set bPlace to yellow
Set color_layer 23 15; #Set tOrigins to light gray
Set color_layer 24 15; #Set bOrigins to light gray
Set color_layer 45 7;  #Set Holes to dark gray
Set color_layer 51 6;  #Set tDocu to mellow yellow
display none; display 1 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 45 51; display -25 -26 -27 -28;

#Assign shortcuts
Assign F8 ratsnest;
Assign AF8 drc;

Assign F9 'Route';
Assign AF9 'Ripup';

Assign F10 'Grid inch 0.05 on; Grid alt inch 0.005;';
Assign AF10 'Grid mm 1 on; Grid alt mm 0.1;';

Assign F11 'display none; display 1 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 45 49 51; display -25 -26 -27 -28;';
Assign AF11 'display none; display 17 20 21 23 27 31 45 51; display -25 -26 -28;';

Assign F12 'show';
Assign AF12 'info';

# Display the bottom side of board and what it will look like in a more human readable view. The "f" is for "flip".
Assign C+F 'RUN SparkFun-Flip.ulp;'

# Turn off everything but the unrouted airwires
Assign C+H 'DISPLAY NONE; DISPLAY 19;'

SCH:
Grid Default; #BHW Reset the grid to the standard value
Change Width 0.006; #BHW Set the 6mil rule
Set XREF_LABEL_FORMAT %F%N/%S; #BHW Remove row & column from default
Change XREF ON; #BHW Default to the labels we use (flag border)
Change Size 0.05; #BHW Use 50mil flags (and text... exceeds minimum)

Assign F9 'Net';
Assign AF9 'Label';

Assign F12 'show';
Assign AF12 'info';

Grid Default;
Change Width 0.008;

#Menu Add Bus Change Copy Delete Display Gateswap Grid Group Invoke Junction \
#     Label Move Name Net Pinswap Quit Script Show Split Value Window ';' \
#     Wire Write Edit;

LBR:


PAC:
#Settings for footprints

SET USED_LAYERS 1 2 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 91 92 93 94 95 96;

Grid inch 0.05 on;
Grid alt inch 0.005;
Set WIRE_BEND 1; #Route with 45 degree angles
Set Drill 0.015; #Make vias 0.02"

#Layer colors
Set palette 16 0xFFFFFFFF; #Super white
Set palette 24 0xFFC0C0C0; #Grey - color used when text is selected (anti palette location 16)
Set color_layer 1 4;   #Set top layer to dark red
Set color_layer 16 1;  #Set bottom layer to dark blue
Set color_layer 17 2;  #Set pads to green
Set color_layer 18 2;  #Set vias to green
Set color_layer 19 6;  #Set unrouted to dark yellow
Set color_layer 20 15; #Set dimension to light gray
Set color_layer 21 16; #Set tPlace to white
Set color_layer 22 14; #Set bPlace to yellow
Set color_layer 23 15; #Set tOrigins to light gray
Set color_layer 24 15; #Set bOrigins to light gray
Set color_layer 45 7;  #Set Holes to dark gray
Set color_layer 51 6;  #Set tDocu to mellow yellow

display none; display 1 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 29 31 45 51;

Assign F10 'Grid inch 0.05 on; Grid alt inch 0.005;';
Assign AF10 'Grid mm 1 on; Grid alt mm 0.1;';

Assign F11 'display none; display 1 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 45 49 51; display -25 -26 -27 -28;';
Assign AF11 'display none; display 17 20 21 23 27 31 45 51; display -25 -26 -28;';


DEV:

Grid Default;
#Menu Add Change Copy Connect Delete Display Export Grid Move Name Package \
#     Prefix Quit Script Show Value Window ';' Write Edit;

SYM:

Grid Default On;
Change Width 0.010;
#Menu Arc Change Copy Cut Delete Display Export Grid Group Move Name Paste \
#     Pin Quit Script Show Split Text Value Window ';' Wire Write Edit;

PAC:

Grid Default On;
Change Width 0.005;
Change Size 0.050;
#Menu Add Change Copy Delete Display Grid Group Move Name Pad Quit \
#     Script Show Smd Split Text Window ';' Wire Write Edit;
```